# How to get selected row's data of datagrid in appropriate text box using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have one problem related to data pop up using WPF when I am click on any row I want to get this data into appropriate text box please refer my code

```
private void Dgrid1_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {


            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\hinal.b\Documents\Database1.accdb");
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select Name,Address,Location from Imfo" , con);
            OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();
                txtname.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                txtadd.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                txtloc.Text = dr[2].ToString();

            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();   



        }
```

Comment: Please don't do this in WPF. Do read up on MVVM.

Comment: @nakiya, while I believe that you are suggesting that the question author doesn't write procedural code in WPF (and generally agree with this), I have to say that for a WPF beginner, your short comment might not make sense... *don't do this*... what's *this*? I *think* that I know what *this* is, but maybe the question author doesn't? It's always best to be clear when leaving advice for new users.

Answer (score 0):

Using data binding, your requirements can be achieved very easily. The `DataGrid` class has a property named `SelectedItem` that relates to whichever item, or row, is currently selected. We can use this property to access the item from the `TextBox` like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" ... />
```

...

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=DataGrid}" />
```

If you just wanted to display one value from the selected item, you could do something like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Propertyname, ElementName=DataGrid}" />
```

However, I see that you have not created a custom data type for your `DataGrid` and so, you will not be able to do that. Please see the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more information about data binding.